# How to prevent my ASP.NET checkbox from being reset on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-applications, postback

I call the following code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Note that this is not my actual code
    //this illustrates what happens
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        CheckBox1.Checked = true;
    }
}
```

but as a result, after a postback the checkbox does not honor my command to set it to 'true' and resets somewhere down the code to whatever user selected in the control.

How to prevent that from happening?

Comment: you have to set it to true AFTER whatever code is setting it to false

Comment: `if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        CheckBox1.Checked = true;
    }`

Comment: So user checks the checkbox and on postback you don't want that checked value to stay?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter: It's not that simple. The postback happens after a change in the DropDownList control, but the checkbox needs to be updated according to a new selection.

Comment: What is triggering the postback, a dropdown selected index change or a button click? Is your desired result that the checkbox is always checked on postback? Are there redirects on postback?

Comment: Can you replicate your results with a simple example and provide us with more code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The postback happens after a change in the DropDownList control, but
>   the checkbox needs to be updated according to a new selection

So, in selected index change event of DropDownList set the  CheckBox1.Checked value

Comment: Yes, I thought of it, but I need to make up controls on the page from Page_Load() depending on that checkbox.

Comment: @c00000fd can you update the question with full code of page load?

Comment: OK. I think I got it fixed. By updating my controls from the event when DropDownList control is changed instead of Page_Load() seems to do the trick. Evidently when you set controls from Page_Load() during postback they are re-initialized later on...

Answer (score 0):

CTRL + F "CheckBox1" there is code somewhere setting it to false

another thing to check is that ViewState is turned on, which it should be by default.  Also set `EnableViewState="true"` of specific checkbox which is also default to true

Comment: No. There's nowhere else in my code that it is set except in one place. It has to do something with that viewstate, or whatever they call it...

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want user selection to persist after postback set `EnableViewState` property of the control to `False`.

Comment: I thought the user set to true , and its getting re-set to false , I reccomended to turn viewstate on , don't really understand the question

Comment: @ScottSelby my understanding was that after selection was made on next postback it doesn't need to persist, but rather be changed by code. I may be wrong tho

Comment: Thank you guys. I did put `EnableViewState="false"` on the checkbox and it didn't help...

Comment: @ScottSelby: As I said above -- The postback happens after a change in the DropDownList control, but the checkbox needs to be updated according to a new selection.

Comment: @c00000fd could you please post your code - how you set the checked value inside of event handler?